# Is this tail recursive or issue with the Kotlin compiler?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, tail-recursion

I am a bit confused with if following function is tail recursive or the Kotlin compiler or IntelliJ Idea has an issue.

As per my understanding this is not eligible for a `tailrec` optimisation because the recursive call is not the last call. Here is the code;

```
    tailrec fun hasRouteBetween(first: GraphNode, second: GraphNode): Boolean {
        if (first.id == second.id) return true

        if (second.children.isEmpty()) return false

        second.visited = true

        for (child in second.children) {
            if (!child.visited) {
                return hasRouteBetween(first, child)
            }
        }
        return false
    }

data class GraphNode(val id: Int, var visited: Boolean = false, val children: LinkedList<GraphNode>)
```

As per the Kotlin docs, forum posts and some SO answers I found, this usage should be flagged as a warning.

I enabled compiler warnings on IntelliJ Kotlin compiler as well. But I don't see any warnings on IntelliJ (IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3 (Ultimate Edition - Build #IU-183.5153.38, built on January 9, 2019) or on Gradle (5.2). I use Kotlin 1.3 with Java 1.8_141.

What am I missing here? (I want to make sure I use `tailrec` correctly, because this code will be shared with others). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function *is* tail recursive. What you need for tail recursion to work is for the recursive call to directly produce the result of the function, and not need any additional processing where the call was made. This is what ensures that the stack of the current function call can be cleared before the recursive call starts, since the data there is not needed anymore.

So for example, this implementation wouldn't work, because it needs to keep the state of the stack at each level of the recursion:

```
var result = false
for (child in second.children) {
    if (!child.visited) {
        if (hasRouteBetween(first, child)) {
            result = true
        }
    }
}
return result
```

Your function doesn't need to do this sort of thing. Inside your `if` statement, you make the recursive call, and at that point whatever the current call had going on is thrown out, because the recursive call's result is all that you need.

---

I'm not sure if your algorithm itself is correct this way, since the very first unvisited child will be the only one that a recursive call is made to.

Comment: thanks @zsmb13, this is beyond my understanding of tail recursion as it seems. Let me digest what you said.

Comment: The important thing for tailrec is that the recursive call has to be the last call on a given execution path of the function. If you always return the result of the recursive call, you've got the tailrec condition satisfied, even if it happens to be in the middle of the function visually.

Comment: thanks for further info and showing the flaw in the algo. I tried to use simple DFS to find if a path exists.